# How I can add folder inside view with Jenkins Job Builder

Tags: python, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-builder

I am creating jobs on my Jenkins server using the [Jenkins Job Builder](https://jenkins-job-builder.readthedocs.io/en/stable/definition.html#view-template).
I can create views, folders, and jobs; however, I am unable to add the folder to the view. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
- job:
    name: jobsBuilderFolder
    project-type: folder

- view:
    name: jobsBuilderView
    view-type: list

- defaults:
    name: jobsBuilderFolder
    folder: jobsBuilderFolder

- job:
    name: MyPipelineJob
    defaults: jobsBuilderFolder
    project-type: multibranch
    .
    .
    .
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was simple, just add the created folder job name under job-name list when creating the view

```
- view:
    name: jobsBuilderView
    view-type: list
    job-name:
      - jobsBuilderFolder
    recurse: true
```